# My FlxGroup does not change it's visibility status

Tags: flixel, haxe

So, I found I needed a different type of button for my game, which I am making using Haxe, OpenFL and HaxeFlixel. After sometime fliding with Haxe, I got following button done, which works just fine. It's not the most sophisticated button, but it gets the job done.

```
class ArrowButton extends FlxGroup
{
    private var spriteUp:FlxSprite;
    private var spriteDown:FlxSprite;
    private var onClick:Void->Void;
    private var x:Float;
    private var y:Float;
    private var traced:Bool;

    public function new(x:Float = 0, y:Float, up = true, onClick:Void->Void = null) 
    {
        super();

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.onClick = onClick;

        if (up)
        {
            spriteUp = new FlxSprite(x, y, Assets.getBitmapData("assets/ArrowUp.png") );
            spriteDown = new FlxSprite(x, y, Assets.getBitmapData("assets/ArrowUpPushed.png") );
        }
        else 
        {
            spriteUp = new FlxSprite(x, y, Assets.getBitmapData("assets/ArrowDown.png") );
            spriteDown = new FlxSprite(x, y, Assets.getBitmapData("assets/ArrowDownPushed.png") );
        }
        add(spriteDown);
        add(spriteUp);
        buttonUp();     
    }

    private function buttonDown():Void
    {
        if (pressed != true)
        {
            spriteUp.visible = false;
            spriteDown.visible = true;
            pressed = true;
        }
    }

    private function buttonUp():Void
    {
        if (pressed = true)
        {
            spriteUp.visible = true;
            spriteDown.visible = false;
            pressed = false;
        }
    }

    private function isClicked():Void
    {
        //trace("Mouse X:Y" + FlxG.mouse.screenX + ":" + FlxG.mouse.screenY + ", button X:Y " + x + ":" + y);

        if (onClick != null && FlxG.mouse.screenX > x && FlxG.mouse.screenX < x + 16 && FlxG.mouse.screenY > y && FlxG.mouse.screenY < y + 16)
        {
            buttonUp();
            onClick();
        }
    }

    override public function destroy()
    {
        super.destroy();
    }

    override public function update()
    {
        if(FlxG.mouse.justReleased())
        {
            isClicked();
        }

        if (FlxG.mouse.pressed() && FlxG.mouse.screenX > x && FlxG.mouse.screenX < x + 32 && FlxG.mouse.screenY > y && FlxG.mouse.screenY < y + 32)
        {
            buttonDown();
        }
        else
        {
            buttonUp();
        }


        super.update();
    }

}
```

Now, I got problem: I can't hide the button. I add this button as a member of another FlxGroup, called systemView. I got several views that I hide and show, depending what menu player is in. So when I move out of systemView, I call function called hideStuff()

```
private function hideStuff():Void
{
        sideMenu.setAll("visible", false, true);
}
```

now, this works fine for everything else, EXCEPT my own button. That one it misses, for some reason. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Fixed the problem by changing it from FlzGroup to FlxSprite, but I would still like to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what went wrong there. Just tested that `setAll("visible", false)` call on a `FlxGroup` and it seemed to be working fine.

A few other things though:

- You should not need to do a `setAll()` for visibility on a `FlxGroup` at all. FlxGroups have a `visible` property themselves, because they extend `FlxBasic`!
- The button you're trying to implement, having a sprite for the `onUp` and one for the `onDown` state, seems extremely similar to `FlxButtonPlus`. Have a look at that!
- You don't need to use `Assets.getBitmapData()` when loading a graphic for a `FlxSprite`. You can just pass the path to the asset as a `String`!
- There's a handy plugin called `MouseEventManager` which lets you create callbacks for mouse events on a `FlxSprite` (`onUp`, `onDown`, `onOver`, `onOut`). [Check the demo out here](http://www.haxeflixel.com/demos/mouseeventmanager). Please note that the demo code only works with the dev version of flixel currently, and that the plugin is still called `MouseInteractionMgr` in the haxelib release (2.0.0-alpha.3). Either way, this plugin would help avoid those region checks in the `update()` function, which could become expensive for a lot of these buttons.

Have fun using HaxeFlixel! If you run into any other issues in the future, it's probably a better idea to post to the [official HaxeFlixel forums](http://www.haxeflixel.com/forum). You're way more likely to get help there, since the engine is not all that well-known currently.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! Yeah, I love HaxeFlixel. In short time, I managed to make pretty good prototype for my game. Still, Haxe is quite different from C++, which I am used to, but it's much more approachable than Actionscript.